# NSApp nextEventMatchingMask with dispatch inside dispatch

Tags: objective-c

I am currently developing an application that runs its own event loop. If i use dispatch async when not enqueued from another dispatch, its block runs correctly.

Example:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"This should appear!");
        });

for (;;)
{
   NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                                untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                                   inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                                  dequeue:YES];

    [NSApp sendEvent:event];
 }
```

If I run this, the log will be called as expected.

But let's say I put a wrap around that dispatch, like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"This should appear!");
    });
    for (;;)
    {
        NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];

        [NSApp sendEvent:event];
    }
});
```

If i run this code, the log will not be executed. I can imagine that since extEventMatchingMask: is being called inside a enqueued block, it will not be able to handle future blocks that are dispatched. But the weird thing is that if I use performSelector: it gets executed even inside a enqueued block.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"This should appear!");
        });

        [self performSelector:@selector(logAppear) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

        for (;;)
        {
            NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                                untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                                   inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                                  dequeue:YES];

            [NSApp sendEvent:event];
        }
    });

-(void) logAppear {
    NSLog(@"This should appear!");
}
```

If I run this example the method logAppear will be called as expected.

So, in short I wanted to ask why the second case doesn't work, and how (if possible) can I run a event loop inside an enqueued block that is able to run dispatch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I realized that what I needed to do was to make sure that that event loop was executed outside any enqueued block. We can do this by putting the loop inside a method and make sure it is called by a performSelector.

Example:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"This should appear!");
        });

        [self performSelector:@selector(logAppear) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

        [self performSelector:@selector(mainLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    });


-(void) mainLoop {
    for (;;)
    {
        NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];

        [NSApp sendEvent:event];
    }
}

-(void) logAppear {
    NSLog(@"This should appear!");
}
```

By running this example we now get both logs as expected